# Word for someone with suggestions but doesn't work themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to describe someone who comes up with lots of ideas and suggestions (especially in team meetings), but when it comes down to implementing and following through on them, they fail to act or simply choose to delegate the work to someone else to avoid doing the work?

Is there even a word for this type of person?

Ex. John couldn't stop talking about his great idea for a basketball tournament last week at the team meeting, but when asked who would organize it, he quieted instantly and suggested that his colleagues follow through on his idea. John is definitely a ...

Comment: Has it struck you that one mark of a good writer is that they can find ways of expressing things that others have not thought of?  This is especially true of descriptions of personal characteristics and behaviour.  If there were a word for every possible characteristic, it might be precise, but it could make writing very dull.

Comment: An "armchair quarterback"?

Comment: Are you asking for something *pejorative* (as your question seems to imply) or something *descriptive*?

Comment: "Armchair quarterback," ha I like that. I was thinking for something pejorative, maybe even condescending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comment by @Cascabel the epithet 'armchair' is often applied to people with volumes of theoretical comment and zero practical experience.

Or, at least, when they do get involved (see below) they make a mess of it.

The epithet benefits from its similarity of sound to the word 'amateur'.

> sharing vicariously in another's experiences
>   - an armchair traveler

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armchair)

> Millions of 'armchair' investors piled into Bitcoin – now they can't sell

[Telegraph .co.uk 27th June 2019](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/investing/news/millions-armchair-investors-piled-bitcoin-now-cant-sell/)

Comment: Armchair quarterback has officially been added to my vocabulary ;)